# Store maximum value for a factor variable and matching observations for that maximum value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am curious how to create another dataset in R, which would store maximum value for a factor variable and matching observation for that maximum value.

Here is a fragment of dataset with just  4 subjects and a code:

`library(data.table) 
my.data <- structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Supervisor = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Emmi", "Pauli"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("01.02.2016 09:45", "01.02.2016 09:48", "01.03.2016 09:55"), class = "factor"), Trials = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Force = c(403.8, 464.6, 567.6, 572.9, 572.4, NA, 533.1, 547, 532.6, 503.8,464.6, 367.6, 372.9), ForceProduction = c(1073, 1149.6, 1944.7, 1906.4, 2260.9, NA, 2634.5, 2471.6, 1187.9, 1073, 1149.6,1944.7, 1906.4)), .Names = c("Subject", "Supervisor", "Time", "Trials", "Force", "ForceProduction"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))`

`DT=as.data.table(my.data)
new.data <- DT[,.SD[which.max(Force)],by=Trials]`

Each subject did 2-4 trials. I need to select max value among all trials for a given subject based on Force. So I am interested in max value of Force column. All other observation related to this max Force should be preserved, those that are not in line with max Force should be abondened.

The code result is strange. Just for 3 subjects, ignoring the rest. And not best trial. But I think that I am totally wrong somewhere.

Can you please direct me to a better solution?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example which can be easily copy&pasted into an R session. [Here are a few tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simply `dplyr` chain that should give you what you want. Grouping by each subject, filter only the values where Force is a maximum for that subject.

```
library(dplyr)

my.data %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  filter(Force == max(Force, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you very much , this works great! Now it should be adjusted for NA, but it is another  story:))

Comment: That's an easy adjustment, `max` has an `na.rm` argument. See updated code.